# Big-O and Big-Omega of a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, big-o

I'm tasked with trying to find the big-O and big-Omega of the given Java method but have no idea how. I know that big-O gives the upper bound and big-Omega gives the lower bound but how exactly am I to figure this out when looking at a program not to mention a recursive one? 
Thank you in advance, this will help immensely in my studies.

```
public static boolean goal(int i, int n){
    if(n == 0){
        if( i == 91) {
            System.out.println("i = " + i +", DONE!!!");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
    else if(i % 2 == 1){
        if(goal(i + 53,n - 1))
        {
            System.out.println("i = "+ i + ", step # " + n);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else {
       if( goal(i + 53,n - 1) || goal(i / 2,n - 1))
       {
            System.out.println("i = "+ i +", step # " + n);
            return true;
       }
       else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a textbook? 99+% of the time, the answer is in the textbook. that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

every recursive iteration you're decreasing n by 1, recursion stops when N reaches 0, in best case yours i is always odd, so you go into first branch, so lower bound of this algorithm is **O(N)**

upper bound is worst case, is your last `else` branch, when you could call `goal` twice, so upper bound will be **O(2^N)**

Answer (score 0):

`goal(i,n)` reduces `n` in every time you call it.

#### Best case

`i` is always odd. Then `goal()` makes only one (at least one) recursive call every time and you get

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + Ω(1),           T(0) = Ω(1)
```

which adds up to `Ω(n)`.

#### Worst Case

`i` is always even. Then `goal()` makes at most two recursive calls evey time and you get

```
T(n) = 2⋅T(n-1) + O(1),         T(0) = O(1)
```

This adds up to

```
Σk=0,...,n 2k⋅O(1) = 2n+1⋅O(1) = O(2ⁿ)
```

Note: This is not very precise. E.g. if `i` is odd, it is in the next call even. If `i` is even and `goal(i + 53,n - 1)` evaluates to `true`, `goal(i / 2,n - 1)` is not called. So maybe we can prove better upper and lower bounds.